# PHFetchResult error in Swift

Tags: objective-c, image, swift, ios8

I translated the code of a project which works perfectly from obj-c in swift. It creates a movie from a array of images that the user imports in the app directly from the `cameraRoll`. If I run the code in the project written in obj-c works fine, but if I run into swift gives me the following error:

> 2014-11-15 13:07:38.535 CEMovieMaker[1278:406246] -[PHFetchResult CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88f1fa20a0
>
> 2014-11-15 13:07:38.536 CEMovieMaker[1278:406246] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PHFetchResult CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f88f1fa20a0'

*** First throw call stack:

```
(
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103891f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102df5bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010389904d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
     3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001037f127c ___forwarding___ + 988
     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001037f0e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
     5   CEMovieMaker                        0x000000010278e655 __53-[CEMovieMaker createMovieFromImages:withCompletion:]_block_invoke + 277
     6   AVFoundation                        0x000000010346db8e -[AVAssetWriterInputMediaDataRequester requestMediaDataIfNecessary] + 88
     7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074c3ba6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074e17f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074c9b22 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1417
     10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074c9432 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
     11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074cbfc1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 685
     12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001074cd5d9 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
     13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001078656cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
     14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001078634a1 start_wqthread + 13
)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)

Here the code:

```
var photoAsset:PHFetchResult!

@IBAction func creaFilmato(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Crea il tuo filmato")
        let img1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "image1.jpg")!
        let settings:NSDictionary = CEMovieMaker.videoSettingsWithCodec(AVVideoCodecH264, withWidth: img1.size.width, andHeight: img1.size.height)
        let prova = CEMovieMaker(settings: settings)
        prova.createMovieFromImages([self.photoAsset.copy()], withCompletion: {(success:Bool, fileURL:NSURL!) in
            if(success){
                self.viewMovieAtURL(fileURL)
                // Save movie in cameraRoll
                let library:ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(fileURL, completionBlock: {(assetURL:NSURL!, error) in
                    if((error) != nil) {
                       println("Errore nel salvataggio del filmato %@",error)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        println("Esportato!")
    }
    func viewMovieAtURL(fileURL:NSURL!)->Void {
        let playerController:MPMoviePlayerViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: fileURL!)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(playerController)
        playerController.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
        playerController.moviePlayer.play()
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    }
```

Can someone help me?

I tried to give the command self.photoAsset.copy(), but the result is always the same . I put this code in obj -c

```
- (IBAction)process:(id)sender {
    
    NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSMutableArray *frames;
    
    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];
    UIImage *img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"];
    UIImage *img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"];
    UIImage *img5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5"];
    
    //frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, nil];
    
    NSDictionary *settings = [CEMovieMaker videoSettingsWithCodec:AVVideoCodecH264 withWidth:img1.size.width andHeight:img1.size.height];
    self.movieMaker = [[CEMovieMaker alloc] initWithSettings:settings];
    
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        
        [frames addObject:img1];
        [frames addObject:img2];
        [frames addObject:img3];
        [frames addObject:img4];
        [frames addObject:img5];
    }
    
    [self.movieMaker createMovieFromImages:[frames copy] withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSURL *fileURL){
        
        if (success) {
            
            [self viewMovieAtUrl:fileURL];
            
            //scrivere qui il codice per salvare il video in camera roll??
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:fileURL
                                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                            if (error)
                                                NSLog(@"Error saving to camera roll: %@",error);
                                            //else
                                            // remove temporary movie file
                                        }];
        }
    }];
}


- (void)viewMovieAtUrl:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [playerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
    [playerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [playerController.moviePlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:playerController.view];
}
```

here function as an in swift , because I pass an array of images. I want instead of the array is composed of all the images in the folder you created by the app

Comment: It looks like you are showing the wrong code. Show `createMovieFromImages:`. Also, is `createMovieFromImages:` still in Objective-C? This could be part of your problem; things may be better when you get it translated into Swift and the types become clearer. It is all but impossible to get an unrecognized selector error in pure Swift - that is one of its advantages.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your error is right here:

```
    prova.createMovieFromImages([self.photoAsset.copy()], withCompletion: {(success:Bool, fileURL:NSURL!) in
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are passing an array that contains one item which is a `PHFectchResult` and that is not what `createMoveFromImages` is expecting.

You will need to put the `UIImages` fetched from Photos into an array of type `[NSObject]` for passing into `createMovieFromImages`.

Comment: Very sensible suggestion (esp. based on the limited info given).

Comment: i have put the objc-code. if I insert a static array works but if I want that the array is composed of the images that the app saves to a folder inside the cameraroll does not work ....

Comment: @AlessioChiappe You have confirmed vacawama's answer and should accept it. In Objective-C, you are passing an array of UIImage objects. In Swift, you are passing an array consisting of one PHFetchResult, a very different thing indeed. Don't.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Can you also write the right code?

Comment: How are you populating `photoAsset`?

Comment: @vacawama in this way: self.photoAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(self.assetCollection, options: nil)

Comment: Where does `self.assetCollection` get set.  Are you actually loading the UIImages anywhere?  For example, are you calling `requestImageForAsset`?

Comment: can you send me your email that i send you directly the project?

Comment: Stack Overflow exists to help others are well who might have the same question in the future.  I'm not sure I could answer the question you have now.  Perhaps you should ask another question that says something like "I need to create an array of UIImages that I load from the Camera roll.  Here is my code to do that.  What else do I need?"

Comment: I see you got an answer to your question about how to load the images.  Does this now work if you pass `images` array?